# Trigger to order a table by date (SQL)

Tags: sql, date, triggers, sql-order-by

I would like to know how to order a table by date(the oldest date first) after the insert of a new value in the same table using a trigger.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RDBMSs (or at least the common ones) have no notion of ordering a table - a table is just a bunch of rows, which the database may return in any arbitrary order.

Your way to control this order is to explicitly declare what order you want them with an `order by` clause in your query:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY last_modification_time
```

Comment: I already knew I can order a table this way but I thought it could be possible to automatically order a table by date after the insert of a new value in the same table. I'm creating a database for a waiting list of patients and I would like to have the list ordered by date in the database. Thank you very much for your quick response though.